# Multiple counters with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a custom react hook to create a counter for each item in a list. the problem is when I increase or decrease a counter, the value of other counters change simultaneously. basically all of the counters show the same value.
here is my custom hook:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useQuantity = (defaultQuantity) => {
const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultQuantity || 1);

const onChange = (e) => {
 if (!+e.target.value >= 1) {
    setValue(1);
    return;
 }
 setValue(+e.target.value);
};

return {
  value,
  setValue,
  onChange,
 };
};
```

how can I change the value of a counter while it doesn't effect the other counters?

This is the component that I map through the items and for each one of them I render the QuantityInput component.

```
import { useQuantity } from "../Hook/useQuantity";
import { QuantityInput } from "./QuantityInput";

export const Order = () => {
    const quantity = useQuantity();

    return (
       orders.map((order) => (
          <QuantityInput quantity={quantity} />
       )
    )
  }
```

and this is QuantityInput component:

```
export const QuantityInput = ({ quantity }) => {

  const decrement = () => {
     quantity.setValue(quantity.value - 1);
  };

  const increment = () => {
    quantity.setValue(quantity.value + 1);
  };

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={decrement}
      disabled={quantity.value === 1}
    >
      -
    </Button>
    <Input {...quantity} />
    <Button onClick={increment}> + </Button>
    );
   };
```

Comment: Hi @OmidJr, please: format your code, and post the Component where you get the issue

Comment: as far as I can see now you only have one counter state can you please explain more what is happening with a single number how are you supposed to keep track of 3 counters?

Comment: @leonardfactory I reformatted the code, you can check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `useQuantity` in your parent component, you should use it in `QuantityInput` component so each of them hold their state.

```
export const QuantityInput = () => {
  const quantity = useQuantity(); // Use quantity here, do not need to pass from props

  const decrement = () => {
     quantity.setValue(quantity.value - 1);
  };

  const increment = () => {
    quantity.setValue(quantity.value + 1);
  };

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={decrement}
      disabled={quantity.value === 1}
    >
      -
    </Button>
    <Input {...quantity} />
    <Button onClick={increment}> + </Button>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you Kong!

Comment: @OmidJr Looking at your code, you don't necessary need a custom hook for your component though. Using setState directly in the component is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The hook that you implemented holds one state value and will only suffice for it.

The solution here is to implement a component that uses this hook. Once you have the component you can render as many instances of it as you want

Also you could simply implement a component instead of custom hook

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const QuantityInput = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.defaultQuantity || 1);

    const onChange = (e) => {
       if (!+e.target.value >= 1) {
          setValue(1);
          return;
       }
       setValue(+e.target.value);
    };

   return (
      <div>
          <div>{value}</div>
          <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      </div>

    )
};


const Parent = ({arr}) => {
   return arr.map(item => <QuantityInput defaultQuantity={item.defaultQuantity} />)
}
```